# SwiftUI preview canvas ignores locale setting

Tags: xcode, swiftui, preview

This doesn't work:

`.environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "es"))`

The preview canvas still shows the english values...
Localization works properly if I run the app on the emulator and change the language in the device settings. But it does not work in the preview canvas.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Text("SomeLocalizableStringKey")
...
static var previews: some View {
        ForEach(["iPhone 8", "iPhone X", "iPhone XS Max"], id: \.self) { deviceName in
            MainContentView()
                .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "es")) // << this seems to be ignored by the preview
                .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName))
                .previewDisplayName(deviceName)
                
            }
    }
```

XCode 12.5.1

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 13.1

Comment: Does not work in Xcode 13.4.1.

Comment: Still having this problem in Xcode 14.2

Comment: You can edit the locale in the scheme settings. Then the preview shows the right format too.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I got it working.

1. Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options -> Set the language you want under App language.
2. Clean Build Folder (Command + Shift + K)